# Classifier learn from model or data

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I'm new in data science. I read [context](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#an-introduction-to-machine-learning-with-scikit-learn) . It saids "The clf (for classifier) estimator instance is first fitted to the model; that is, it must learn from the model. ...."
and example shows:
`>>>clf.fit(digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1])`

I don't understand why clf classifier "learn from the model". As example shows, I think classifier should learn from data, since it fits data to the clf classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a typo to me.

As part of your learning journey, you could contribute a change in that tutorial replacing "model" with "data". See [How to contribute scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#documentation). The sources of that tutorial are [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/doc/tutorial/basic/tutorial.rst)

Comment: thank you. I think I'll learn more.